# ASP .net GridView DropDownList - Select from Distinct values

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a SQL table (Trade Mapping) with the following columns:

- BTF_TRADE_MAPPING_KEY    int
- BTF_SYSTEM_CODE  varchar
- BACHE_CATEGORY_DESC  varchar

I need a grid view to enable users to edit the data from a website. The problem is the category column. When the user edits a row it needs to display a distinct list of categories from a categories table into a drop-down list - template field. I have the table displaying ok, in select mode all is good. However, I can't get the update to work. Has anyone come across example code of how to get this kind of scenario to work?

Many thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx